# Strange result ADC(Arduino Micro) Thermistor KTY 10-6

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, adc, temperature, thermistor

**Where's the error in the following circuit/code ?**

Some time ago i got various sensors . One of those was the kty 10-6 (3 pieces). At the beginning i could not find any datasheet or examples about this temperature sensor. So i got an LM35 which was very simple to setup as it is linear. Now after various months i finally found the proper datasheet and the Mathematical equation to get the proper resistor values.

[KTY 10-6](https://www.pollin.de/shop/downloads/D180003B.PDF) **(this is the datasheet link)**

**Circuit**

I found out that it is similar to the kty81-210

```
 (Vcc 5+)--+-->2.7k--+-->kty81-110-->(GND)
           |         |
           +->100nF--+-----> ADC0 (Analog Port 0)
```

As i have no 2.7k Ω resistor i used a **2200 ohm** resistor.

the capacitor is 100nf i think: **IJ63** is on top of the enclosure.**correct?**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJkj5A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Code**

As this thermistor is not linear and i always wanted to use the proper mathematical [formula](http://nicuflorica.blogspot.ro/2013/01/arduino-ca-termometru-folosind-senzorul_22.html) to calculate the temperature, this is the best solution. Based on what i read in the kty10-6 datasheet i changed some values like the resistor and the beta(a) value. the alpha(b) .00788 seems to be the same in both sensors.

```
float resistor = 2200; // changed
float temp = analogRead(A5);
float ukty = 5*temp/1023.0;
float a = 0.00001937*1000; // changed
float b = 0.00788*1000;
float c = 1000-resistor*ukty/(5-ukty);
float delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;
float delta1 = sqrt (delta);
float x2 =(-b + delta1)/(2 * a);
float temp1 = x2 + 25 ;
```

**Is the calculation correct?**

I ask beacuse even if its really hot these days .. i don't think there are 132-135°Celsius.The formula is for celsius.

Even if i don't use this formula but use other simpler calculations (linear) i always get over 130-140°Celsius

[source1](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/Kty81-110)   [source2](http://www.schmidt-welt.net/weblog/arduino-and-kty81-210/)  [source3](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-read-temperatures-with-arduino--mac-53714)

**Notes**

If i touch the sensor the reading increases... as expected.

I tested on all analog pins.

I use the arduino micro.

I use it with a i2cLCD.

It's usb powered.

Nothing else is connected.

If i measure the resistor on the proto board when everything is turned off i read it as 1200ohm... the cap?

**Why do i get 120 to 140 as a temperature value?**

---

**Optional**

I just closed a post on electronics stack wich describes how to increase the thermistors resolution with resistors.
[found it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68743/expanding-range-of-analog-values-from-temperature-sensor)

If someone knows how to change my circuit to read temperatures from -10/-20 to +40/+50 i would be very happy. this would duplicate the resolution. i think in my zone the temperatures will never go lower than -20 or higher than +50 ° Celsius.

I buyed 3 of those, i know they are cheap. I know about the nice DS##### Temp sensor which is perfect for the microcontrollers. But i want to get this one to work also.

Comment: Couldn't find any info - strange. I put Thermistor KTY 10-6 and got this straight away https://www.pollin.de/shop/downloads/D180003B.PDF

Comment: when i started using microcontyrollers... some months ago i searched for something like KIT 10 ... as the text on those temperature sensors are very degraded. anyway yeah i found it... it's an infineon... i also added the link in the post.its the first link just to be shure that if someone reads this he has easy access to it.

Comment: appart from that nice link , you have any ideas what could i have done wrong? i'm not an electronical enginer.

Comment: Added "this is the datasheet link" to the post if someone else misses it

Comment: Looking at the resistance at 25 degrees you should get a resistance of about 2000 ohm giving about 2.4V across the sensor. A quick check with a voltmeter should verify this. This should produce a reading of about 490 in the adc. Plug this value into your calculation and MANUALLY work through your program (pencil and paper). What value of temperature does it give ? (correct answer should be around 25) - If it doesn't then your formula/program is wrong

Comment: the reading on a scale of 1023max was around 495-500. so it's prolly correct as there where around 28-32°C.

Comment: and the formula is wrong. like i said the reading was the same on all analog pins...

Comment: what about the alpha beta ? are those values i put in correct? 0.00001937 &  0.00788?

Comment: the "formula" link inside the code description shows where i got it. his example works on a different kty sensor. while it appears that in my eyes the lines of code are the same i may miss something or put the wrong values in ...

Comment: And so also looks the formula inside the datasheet. even if i have difficulties(heavy) to read formulas written that way. it looks like to be the same as in the c++ code.

Comment: If i touch the sensor... which is around 129-133 after the math at a temp of 28-32deg... it goes up slowly to 134 135 136... As i could just do: "result -100"... but for shure that is wrong.

Comment: and yeah... the real resistor value i use is 2160-2170... so i put 2170 in that field and not 2200.but thats again another story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that analog readings will vary between 0 (=0V) and 1023 (5V).

First step is to convert the reading of the analog value (of voltage) into an actual **resistance** value.

[image]

*Suggested new program (haven't tested this so comments/corrections welcome)*

```
float resistorfixed = 2200;
float temp = analogRead(A5);

// calculate sensor resistance value (Rkty)

float Rkty = (resistorfixed * temp) / (1023 - temp);

// From the data sheet the value of the resistance of the sensor 
// @ 25 degrees is 2000 +/- 20 ohmsStart with calculating the measured 
// resistance.

float R25 = 2000;

// We are also given alpha and beta 

float alpha = 7.88 / 1000;
float beta  = 1.937 / 100000; // divide by 10^-5

// Now we need to calculate the temperature factor (KayTee)

float KayTee = Rkty / R25;

// We now have all the information to calculate the actual temperature 
// (AcT)

float AcT = 25 + ((sqrt((alpha * alpha) - (4 * beta) + (4 * beta * KayTee)) - alpha) / (2 * beta));

// Just hope I've got my brackets is the correct place!
```

Comment: You should consider developing the habit of avoiding floats where possible